# How to forward internet connection at eth2 to LAN at eth1?

Tags: networking, ip-forward

I have two network cards/connections:

- eth2 is connected to the internet
- eth1 is connected to my LAN

*I want to allow the computers in the LAN on eth1 to access my internet connection on eth2.*

Please provide me a detailed step-by-step guide or tutorial to help me solve this, as I am a beginner in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

First, determine the ips of your network cards.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
ifconfig -a
```

Let's assume are:

```
eth2 10.0.10.2  --- Internet
eth1 10.0.20.5  --- LAN
```

**Note:** Change the IPs by your cards IPs

Then disable network manager and manually configure the static ips.

Run in the terminal:

```
nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Set "managed=false", shown under [ifupdown]

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Then in /etc/network/interfaces, add information about the interfaces:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Set this:

```
The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2      # internet
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.10.0/24
gateway 10.0.10.1

auto eth1  # lan 
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static 
address 10.0.20.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.20.0/24
broadcast 10.0.20.255
gateway 10.0.10.1
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

And for a simple example of NAT, run:

```
/sbin/iptables -F  
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.20.0/24 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t  nat  -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.20.0/24 -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If everything works correctly, create a script to be run at startup

```
sudo -i    
nano /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh
```

Put this content

```
#! /bin/sh
/sbin/iptables -F              &&echo
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.20.0/24 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t  nat  -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.20.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

And continue run:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh /etc/rcd.2/s99my_iptables.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh /etc/rcd.3/s99my_iptables.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh /etc/rcd.4/s99my_iptables.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh /etc/rcd.5/s99my_iptables.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/my_iptables.sh /etc/rcd.S/s99my_iptables.sh
update-rc.d my_iptables.sh defaults
```

Comment: Excellent answer (and an upvote!) just moved the note up where it belongs and a few minor edits...  ;-)